# Dual monitor on Macbook Pro Retina: difference between 13 and 15 inches?

Tags: display, macbook-pro

Can the HD 4000 of the Macbook Pro Retina 13 easily handle 2 monitor at 1920x1080 or would it be better to buy a Macbook Pro Retina 15 because it has a separate GPU ? At the Macbook Retina's release, I heard it had some scrolling issues because of the large resolution it had to deal with and I do not want to experience that on external displays.
I plan to plug the 2 monitors on the 2 thunderbolt ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HT5219 Thunderbolt ports and displays: Frequently asked questions (FAQ)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219?viewlocale=en_US#dispnum) says the 13" Retina Macbook Pro will happily run with two Thunderbolt displays.

Although I have not used it first hand, I would not expect you to have performance issues running the two extra displays. The main retina display is actually drawing 4 times as many pixels as the external displays, and then scaling the image down, so a Thunderbolt display is not going to make much of a difference.

As to the scrolling performance, I believe that was [fixed in a software update](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6495/latest-webkit-build-doubles-scrolling-performance-on-macbook-pro-with-retina-display)