# MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) Dual External Monitor Performance

Tags: macbook-pro, display

According to the [MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP715?locale=en_US), the Graphics and Video Support for the 2015 Retina MBP 13-inch is:

> - Intel Iris Graphics 6100
> - Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 3840 by 2160 pixels on up to two external displays, both at millions of colors.

There exist [answered questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182152/2015-mbp-external-monitor-options) here on the Apple Stack Exchange about *what's possible* in terms of dual external monitors for this MBP. I understand that, as shown by the above quoted text, it is possible to run two 4K monitors with the MBP.

My question is concerned with the actual *performance* of using two full 2160p/4K external monitors with (at least) a Mini DisplayPort connection - has anyone had any problems (flickering, or really anything negative) with this setup? Similar to  [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85099/dual-monitor-on-macbook-pro-retina-difference-between-13-and-15-inches), but for the 2015 MBP.

I guess the performance may vary with the brand of monitor, but I'm just looking for a general idea of how well it does. I'm interested in knowing about how it would function before I make the costly investment.

I know the Intel Iris Graphics 6100 are [integrated](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204349) and use up to 1.5GB RAM of the MBP, but I don't know if that will mean a stable, reliable experience with two 4K monitors. I also know the Retina 15-inch 2015 MacBook Pro uses a discrete graphics card, which may be more suitable, but I'm not interested in the 15-inch screen.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same question, and found the answer on Apple's discussion forums:

> A final update - I got my hands on two Dell P2715Q's which support 3840x2160@60Hz over SST. I'm happy to report the new 13" RMBP happily drives both displays at their native resolutions with 60Hz refresh in single stream mode (the default).

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6868583